# cloned my website to upgrade now original website is broken

Tags: upgrade

I wanted to upgrade magento but i didn't want it to disturb my website so i made a clone of my website in cpannel, and ran the upgrade on that which seemed to work perfectly.

standard website: www.mydomain.com
clone site: www.mydomain.com/ecommerce

However when i go back to my old website (www.mydomain.com) the home page will load but every time i go to click a link it say:

404 Not found The resource requested could not be found on this server!

for example it will try to go to a link www.mydomain.com/shoes but this doesnt work, however www.mydomain.com/ecommerce/shoes does work. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: I think the problem is, that you copied the local.xml while cloning, so the second magento installation wrote in the live database and the updates from 1.9 are not backwards compatible.

Comment: but the new cloned websites local.xml points to a different database than the original website?

Comment: Was that the case all the time? If not, the update ran on the old database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you copied the local.xml while cloning, so the second magento installation wrote in the live database and the updates from 1.9 are not backwards compatible.

So I see two ways: recover the database from backup you made before (YOU MADE A BACKUP BEFORE, YES!?)

Or do the backup until it is finalized, problem with the url is probably a wrong base_url you can set in the admin backend System > Configuration > Web

And after this, you should reindex everything - hopefully you don't have a lot of products.

Comment: yea i have database back up i made yesterday before doing any of this as i had never done a magento upgrade before and knew it could go wrong. Thank you though and i will try this and let you know if i have any problems

Comment: so if i reinstall my backed up database and then delete my cloned website things SHOULD go back to normal ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can actually update your base_url from backend as system will automatically forward you old site. You probably need to update your database directly. To change your base url execute a query (or do something similar on your GUI):

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like '%base_url%';
```

This will display something similar:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| config_id | scope    | scope_id | path                  | value              |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|         5 | default  |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url | http://old.com/    |
|         6 | default  |        0 | web/secure/base_url   | http://old.com/    |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

To change base url update the data (use your config_id-s and base url values):

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://new.com/' WHERE config_id IN (5, 6);
```

This will update appropriate records and you can continue working on backend as usual. Naturally you can use GUI to change those fields as well.

PS. Don't forget url trailing slash, Magento does not work without it ...