# transferred host but site not loading

Tags: index

Howdie,

Ive transferred my site to a new host, upgrading to a VPS in the process.

Cant get the homepage to load though, if I browse to the URL i get page not found. /test.php loads fine.

Ive copied in the original index.php file from the install directory but still cant get the site to load.

Sure im missing something straight forward?

Any pointers, greatly appreciated - free pint for any assistance!

Cheers

Comment: Try browsing www.site.com/index.php and let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you Move your Site one Domain to another Domain Then you have to make sure below Things.

1) First Open Your FTP remove var/cache Folder.
2) Open Your DataBase open Table `core_config_data` find

```
web/unsecure/base_url = To new URL
web/secure/base_url   = To new URL
```

3) If your database is same then it's not a problem but if you also move your database then you have to change the detail in `app/etc/local.xml` file.

4) Also check .htaccess file like if you have put some redirection rules or not.

5) Refresh your link.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

1) If your domain name has changed, be sure to update the following in your core_config_data table: (Disregard if the domain name has not changed)

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_url
```

2) Clear the following folders on your server

```
var/cache/*
var/sessions/*
var/locks/*
```

3) Make sure that when you transferred you files that you also transferred the .htaccess

4) Double check your database credentials match your mysql server located at:

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

Let us know how that has worked for you

Comment: @Mark Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure everything is set correctly in Configuration > Web. Primarily the URLs and CMS Homepage. I'm assuming you can access admin?

Comment: Hi, Nope cant see admin either, get the error;

Comment: Ah ok. I'm assuming then you aren't using a copy of the original database? Try [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21783/7927) and let us know how it goes. Also, have you upgraded Magento in the process?

Comment: ahh well thats interesting, that returns an IP and not a URL, surely thats not correct.

Comment: and no... havnt upgraded. And yes im usng the original database, but have changed the domain name in the process.

Comment: Change to the correct URL if you're seeing an IP. Your domain change will be the issue here.

Comment: Check your file permissions on the new server, especially var/ and subfolders...